# Xdebug not working with PHP 5.5.0 beta1 on Windows

Tags: php, zend-framework, xdebug, beta

I've installed the latest **php 5.5.0 beta1** on Windows x64 with Apache 2.4 (TS).

I cannot get **Xdebug** to work though.

I'm wondering if anyone knows if Xdebug is simply not supported with the new php beta yet or if I'm doing it wrong. I've spent the last hour trying every known issue on the net.

**Environment**

```
Apache Version Apache/2.4.4 (Win64) PHP/5.5.0beta1
Compiler MSVC11 (Visual C++ 2012)
```

**What I've done**

- **httpd.conf** `LoadModule php5_module "E:\wamp\php\php5apache2_4.dll"`
- **php.ini** `zend_extension=E:\wamp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll`
- **E:\wamp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll**  `php_xdebug-2.2.1-5.4-vc9-x86_64`
- **php.exe -m** `Failed loading E:\wamp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll`
- **php.exe -i** from command line produces following error (*which goes away if I comment out the zend_extension line in php.ini*):

  **php.exe - Entry Point Not Found**
  `The procedure entry point zend_unmangle_property_name could not be located in the dynamic link library php5ts.dll`

**Xdebug Wizard Output**

Also, the results of my phpinfo in http://xdebug.org/wizard.php is below. I'm not sure why it says I'm using VC6 when phpinfo says VC11...

```
Summary

Xdebug installed: no
Server API: Command Line Interface
Windows: yes - Compiler: MS VC6 - Architecture: x64
Zend Server: no
PHP Version: 5.5.0
Zend API nr: 220121212
PHP API nr: 20121212
Debug Build: no
Thread Safe Build: yes
Configuration File Path: C:\Windows
Configuration File: E:\wamp\php\php.ini
Extensions directory: E:\wamp\php\ext
The compiler (MS VC6) that this PHP was build with, is no longer supported. Please upgrade to a version that was built with MS VC9.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the latest xdebug supports only php 5.4. Xdebug needs exactly the same php version to work.

Comment: That is what I would guess just wanted to confirm. Thanks.